# Monitor Import Wizard Job Status?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, bulk-api

Is there a way to check Status of 1st Batch job every 5 mins by using 2nd batch job? Here 1st batch job internally uses 'Import Wizard' to load/Delete records and everything handles in Salesforce Connectors. (So we cannot append our code in 1st Batch job)

Comment: Do you want to invoke a batch job every 5 minutes or check the result of a bulk data load? Title and question do not seem to match, especially since you say you cannot tapped code to your "batch job" which implies it is from an external system using the bulk api

Comment: @Eric - I modified the question. Yes the 1st Batch job is invoked by External System (Mule ESB). So I want to write an other Batch Apex which periodically (every 5 or 10min) checks the 1st Batch job Status and if there are any failed batches, want to send an Email. I don't think using Scheduler we can Invoke code more than once in a day right?

Comment: Sure you can...in fact this question may be a duplicate as far as the scheduling aspect. [How to run Apex code every 5 minutes in 2016?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119655/how-to-run-apex-code-every-5-minutes-in-2016)

Comment: Thanks for routing me to right post. You can mark this as Duplicate.