# call Messaging Queue every 5 Minutes

Tags: apex, integration, callout, design-patterns

I want to make Integration between Salesforce and ActiveMQ(Is is a messaging server where the company send and save messages in this service).

The Context:

Every 5 Minutes should salesforce a request to ActiveMQ send to bring the message from ActiveMQ to salesforce, where salesforce will hanlde the message to extract Information from it.

The Question:
What is the best design patter to achieve that? 
I read about many pattern, but I do not what is the best.

Comment: Do you want SF to poll ActiveMQ?

Comment: Yes I want that @PranayJaiswal

Comment: We there are Apex Scheduler that allows you to perform a job periodically, You might wanna investigate that: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: I would say the best design pattern is to use some middleware solution to monitor ActiveMQ and push messages to Salesforce over the API. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119655/how-to-run-apex-code-every-5-minutes-in-2016) for some of the challenges related to scheduling Apex on a tight schedule. Salesforce is not well suited to this activity.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of pulling data after Salesforce's initiated request... you can push data from server to Salesforce where you have hosted ActiveMQ - where you can run your cron job to run after each 5 minutes.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for you answer. The problem that I should make the call from salesforce. I know Scheduling Apex had some problems, therefore I need a good design pattern to handle this thing. What do you think about queueable  apex?

Comment: @kibitzer Can you give me you opinion?

Comment: Why cant Active MQ periodically send data to SF instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think this design architecture is a mistake. (Disclaimer: I don't have experience with ActiveMQ).

I would say the best design pattern is to use some middleware solution to monitor ActiveMQ and push messages to Salesforce over the API. It is *possible*, albeit far more complicated than you would expect, to schedule code to run every five minutes. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119655/how-to-run-apex-code-every-5-minutes-in-2016) for some of the challenges and techniques related to scheduling Apex on a tight schedule.

Even then, you are subject to the vagaries of server load and Salesforce's internal balancing systems. You have no guarantee that any form of asynchronous Apex - Scheduled or Queueable, future or Batch - will execute on the specific schedule that you are hoping for, and the performance you observe *will* vary from time to time. If you are building a system that depends on very regular updates in Salesforce, you're setting yourself up for a lot of support and maintenance challenges as you move forward.

Salesforce is not well suited to this activity. It's much more sustainable to use a general-purpose server or middleware platform to support Salesforce.